# How to log calls to deprecated fields in apollo server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

We marked some fields in our schema using the `@deprecated` directive. Now we want to log if these fields are still in use from some of our clients. What would be the best way to do this, without using Apollo Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the client code, then you can utilize [GraphQL Inspector](https://graphql-inspector.com/docs/essentials/validate) to check for deprecated usage. Using the CLI, you just do:

```
graphql-inspector validate DOCUMENTS SCHEMA
```

where `DOCUMENTS` is a glob pattern used to match the files containing the queries and `SCHEMA` is a pointer to the schema used for validation. The files containing the queries can be `.graphql` files or `.js`/`.ts` files. The schema pointer can be a URL to your schema or one or more `.graphql` files with your schema's type definitions. See [here](https://graphql-inspector.com/docs/api/schema) and [here](https://graphql-inspector.com/docs/api/documents) for additional ways to provide the schema and documents.

If you don't have access to the client code, or specifically need to log deprecated usage *on every request*, then you can write your own [Apollo Server plugin](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins) and utilize GraphQL Inspector's [programmatic API](https://graphql-inspector.com/docs/installation#programatic-api) instead to validate each request's parsed document as it comes in. The parsed document will be available beginning with the [validationDidStart](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/#validationdidstart) lifecycle hook. See the docs for a complete example of how to write your own plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As we have to go with the second option I wonder where to I get the `Source` that is needed for the `validate` function. Checking the types for for `validate` it looks like it expects sources to be a list of `Source` but this is not provided by the `validationDidStart` arguments where `source` is just a string.

Comment: Sorry, the API usage is not very well documented. You should import `Source` from `graphql` and then create an instance of the class using the query string. Check out the tests [here](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/graphql-inspector/blob/master/packages/core/__tests__/validate.ts) for correct usage.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot. Works as expected.

Comment: Is there any way to get the name of the deprecated field out of the error object